# ZF2 how to dynamically select modules / controllers

Tags: module, zend-framework2, bootstrapping

I'm building a CMS where every page will be a node with a NodeID. I would like to dynamically decide which ZF2 module to use based on node type.

I assume the best place to decide is core's module (application) onBootstrap() method, as I didn't find anything like "postRoute" event in ZF1.

The question is, how can I correctly pass processing to correct Module / Controller ? I mean what is the correct place to do that. Is that really onBootstrap() in App. module, or is there something more appropriate ?

Comment: Using this flowchart: http://okeowoaderemi.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/zf2-flowchart1.jpg You might be able to extend or hook into the module manager to do what you want, but it seems like a very unique/abnormal workflow.

Comment: thank yout for the hint, I'll check it.

Comment: btw,  I'ts not very typical setup, but how to manage different node types.. everything in the Application/Index ? :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this would be to use routers to direct flow to the appropriate controller.  You haven’t specified how you plan to access your pages, but assuming that page access is done by creating hyperlinks to page-specific url’s, you can configure your modules so that links go to the proper url, which in turn directs to the proper controller.

1. Add (or make sure that you already have) a column in your pages
   table that identifies the node type.  (You’ll also need to set up
   some form of validation to ensure that the values in this column are
   limited to values that you will have routers for.)
2. Grab the node type data when you grab the NodeID from the table.
3. Set up your hyperlinks to send both the node type and the NodeID to
   a url together.  Examples might be www.mysite/about/node3, www.mysite/info/node7, and www.mysite/contact/node9.
4. Set up your routers so the url’s lead to the right controller.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have point 1 and 2 exactly as you wrote - simply NestedSet with class type per each node. This is what I need:

1. to get class name from DB afterr URL is decompiled
2. where to do this part ? onBootstrrap ? Core IndexController ?
3. call correct module / controller

Point is, that I don't like to do any redirect or URL rewrite, maybe I can build this on simple Controller forward plugin ?
OK, finally these are 2 questions, not one :) Where to place "decider" and how to select module / controller.

Comment: I mean I can do that by "brute force" in the Index/Index, but I like to follow ZF2 model..